# One framework for Dependency injection (in MVC app) and for simple AOP task (using attributes)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, aop

I have come to the point where I want to accomplish 2 tasks in my ASP.NET application that both can be done using some AOP framework but they are both of different nature:

1. Dependency injection for my controllers and services
2. I have created custom attribute `NotNullAttribute` and marked some method's parameters or properties with it instead of of throwing `ArgumentNullException` if those parameters or properties were null. I want AOP framework to check for those attributes in compile time and add throw causes instead. Example follows:

   ```
   //original code that I write
   public void MyMethod([NotNull]string param1){
       //do something
   }
   ```

   .

   ```
   //code actually being compiled - after AOF processing/weaning  
   public void MyMethod(string patam1){
       if(param1 == null){
           throw new ArgumentNullException("param1");
       }
       //do something
   }
   ```

So I want framework (does not even have to be AOP necessarily but I guess it would have to be) that will allow me to do both those task simply.

I have some additional requirements:

- small footprint, 1 or 2 assemblies
- integration to VS - I just want to press `Ctrl+F5` to compile and the framework does it work, injects dependencies, adds exception throwing code *without* me even knowing about it. I don't want to run pre-compilation from command line or anything like that.
- for exception throwing code generation I'd like write classes. Like regular aspects. Not XML, no configuration (conventions are acceptable). For dependency injection I also prefer classes but XML or another config file is acceptable but it should be simple enough to use by somebody who don't really know XML and don't really like it.

Is there some such framework ? If there are more what are they pros/cons ?

---

**EDIT:** Oh yes I forgot very important think: The framework should be for free.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have any personal experience with it, but I think [Linfu](http://code.google.com/p/linfu/) fits your description.

Apart from that, you can get AOP-like behavior from DI Containers with **dynamic interception** - here's an example: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/20/InstrumentationWithDecoratorsAndInterceptors.aspx

The following DI Containers support interception out of the box:

- [Castle Windsor](http://castleproject.org/container/index.html)
- [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/)
- [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/)

Pure AOP (without DI) can be had with [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp).

Comment: Thank you it is helpful. PostSharp was the first think T tried but it is not free...

Comment: @drasto: There are significant bits of PostSharp that were very much free last time I looked - it's no hobbled taster and definitely important to consider in this space; the paid bits are extremely powerful things that go beyond core AOP (Eve if you may actually be right in your context, I just didnt like the way in which you expressed your brushoff!)

Comment: Agreed @drasto, the free bits from PostSharp are more than sufficient to accomplish what you're looking to do and is a very solid framework by the by.  Lots of good examples on the site too.